# ng-hide and ng-show for current row

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have one table.In than am doing row hide and show using angular for edit and save purpose.
It's working fine.

```
$scope.init=function(){
    $scope.editable=true;
}
```

Now when I click on edit button in  table row ,edit button will be hided and save button will be shown.

```
$scope.editRow = function(id){
    console.log(id);\\row id will be displayed here
    $scope.editable=false;
}
```

Here am facing one problem ,if I click edit on second row ,only second row should be editable.
I know we can do this easily using row id in jquery.But here I don't know how to do this in angular for `ng-hide` and `ng-show`.
Any Help?Thanks!!

code:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>                                
    <th>Qualification</th>
    <th>Course</th>
    <th>Grade Attained</th>                                
    <th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="detail in educationDetails">
    <td>
        <span ng-show="editable">{{detail.qualification}}</span>  
        <input type="text" ng-model="detail.qualification" ng-hide="editable"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span ng-show="editable">{{detail.education_type}}</span>   
        <input type="text" ng-model="detail.education_type" ng-hide="editable"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span ng-show="editable">{{detail.grade}}</span>          
        <input type="text" ng-model="detail.grade" ng-hide="editable"/>
    </td>
    <td>      
        <div ng-show="editable">
            <span><i class='fa fa-trash-o' ng-click="deleteEducationDetail(detail)"></i></span>
            <span><i class='fa fa-pencil' ng-click="editEducationDetail(detail)"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div ng-hide="editable">
            <span><i class='fa fa-floppy-o' ng-click="updateEducationDetail(detail)"></i></span>
            <span><i class='fa fa-times' ng-click="cancelEducationDetail(detail)"></i></span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>





$scope.init = function () {
$scope.editable = true;
}
$scope.editEducationDetail = function (detail) {
detail.editable = false;
}
```

Comment: you need to have an array for each row

Comment: yes am having an array.

Comment: pass the object and make the editable true of the particular object

Comment: ok am passing an object into method.But How can I make only that row to be editable?

Comment: just whatever yourobj.editable = true;

Answer (score 1):

In order to make each row editable, you can pass the row object inside the function and make editable true as follows,

```
 $scope.editRow = function(rowobject){
    rowobject.editable=true;
 }
```

code:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>                                
    <th>Qualification</th>
    <th>Course</th>
    <th>Grade Attained</th>                                
    <th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="detail in educationDetails">
    <td>
        <span ng-show="editable">{{detail.qualification}}</span>  
        <input type="text" ng-model="detail.qualification" ng-hide="editable"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span ng-show="editable">{{detail.education_type}}</span>   
        <input type="text" ng-model="detail.education_type" ng-hide="editable"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span ng-show="editable">{{detail.grade}}</span>          
        <input type="text" ng-model="detail.grade" ng-hide="editable"/>
    </td>
    <td>      
        <div ng-show="editable">
            <span><i class='fa fa-trash-o' ng-click="deleteEducationDetail(detail)"></i></span>
            <span><i class='fa fa-pencil' ng-click="editEducationDetail(detail)"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div ng-hide="editable">
            <span><i class='fa fa-floppy-o' ng-click="updateEducationDetail(detail)"></i></span>
            <span><i class='fa fa-times' ng-click="cancelEducationDetail(detail)"></i></span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>





$scope.init = function () {
$scope.editable = true;
}
$scope.editEducationDetail = function (detail) {
detail.editable = false;
}
```

Comment: still you ar enot passing the row object

Comment: Where ? I don't see anything as such

Comment: sorry I have updated my code in wrong place.check now.

Comment: Check this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/aOHKQPGKV1lNIGEC2Iwt?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve that you need show/hide properties for each row. You can initialise a property in ng-init and use it to show/hide rows. You can also do all of the show/hide logic in your html with the below code.

```
<tr ng-repeat="detail in educationDetails" ng-init="detail.editable = false">
    <td>
        <span ng-show="!detail.editable">{{detail.qualification}}</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="detail.qualification" ng-show="detail.editable" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <span ng-show="!detail.editable">{{detail.education_type}}</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="detail.education_type" ng-show="detail.editable" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <span ng-show="!detail.editable">{{detail.grade}}</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="detail.grade" ng-show="detail.editable" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <div ng-show="editable">
            <span><i class='fa fa-trash-o' ng-click="deleteEducationDetail(detail)"></i></span>
            <span><i class='fa fa-pencil' ng-click="detail.editable = true"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div ng-hide="editable">
            <span><i class='fa fa-floppy-o' ng-click="updateEducationDetail(detail)"></i></span>
            <span><i class='fa fa-times' ng-click="detail.editable = false"></i></span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```